# assigning weight for attributes in dataset

Tags: python, classification

How can I assign weight for attributes in dataset before training model and which best method to achieve that in python?

Comment: I think that assigning weights manually it isn't a great idea. Machine learning works out the importance of features by itself. Why don't try to select them?

Comment: Thanks, Agostino Dorano.

Comment: Do you mean, using feature selection to choose the important features ?

Answer (score 1):

Only for certain models.

For example for mlp you have this possibility:

The [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) show you the attributes in use.

> Attributes:
>   ...
>
> `coefs_` : list, length n_layers - 1
>   The ith element in the list represents the weight matrix corresponding to > layer i.
>
> `intercepts_` : list, length n_layers - 1
>   The ith element in the list represents the bias vector corresponding to layer > i + 1.

Just build your classifier `clf=MLPClassifier(solver="sgd")` and set `coefs_` and `intercepts_` before calling `clf.fit()`.

Comment: Thanks Noah Weber.